# MongoDB: Fetching every document from a collection

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm creating a discord bot in python. I'm using MongoDB Atlas (NoSQL)

I have a user's document which looks like this

```py
"user": 12345,

"created_at": 2012-12-31 01:48:24
```

I wanted to fetch every document in a collection and then take it's `created_at`.

How can I do this? I tried with `db.inv.find({})`, but it didn't work. I checked MongoDB's documentation, but they only told about JavaScript. How can I fetch **every** document in my collection?

Comment: Try `db.inv.find()`?

Comment: You added tag `python`; you looking for this in python?   And:  What did not work?  No rows back?   More fields than just `created_at` if that is what you are targeting?

Answer (score 0):

`db.inv.find()` will give you the cursor object to all the documents and then you need to iterate on it's returned documents to get the specified field.

Make sure you have connected to right collection

```
result=db.inv.find()
for entry in result:
    print(entry["created_at"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your db is the database inside mongodb.if your db is mongdb's `client.db`,your code is right.

```
MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://user:password@host:port/"
client= pymongo.MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
# database
db = client.db
# db.collection.find({}) will get the item list
result = db.inv.find({})
```